# connection string of postgresql that can run on server or network in C#

Tags: c#, postgresql

return `User ID=postgres;Password=root;Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=axestack;`

this is my connection string but i am only able to run my application only in localmachine,when i am trying to run this application exe on other machine it not responding or showing error like:`Backend sent unrecognised unresponse type`.
how to solve this please provide me some suggestions or code for connection string so i can run my `applection.exe` on other machine.

Comment: check the user id and password and dbname is same as your system with the application running system.

Comment: please somebody provide me the connection string.